# Matlab - is it possible to track changes in the code from beginning to the final version?

Tags: matlab, version-control, coding-style

Instead of saving the file in different names as it evolves, is there a way to automatically keep track of each and every change since code inception (conception) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) tools such as CVS, SVN etc.

You can check out Matlab's integration with version control tools [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/source-control.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, please? So I setup source control and all the changes are automatically tracked?

Comment: If you have a Simulink license handy, you could check out Simulink Project.  It's a project manager which integrates with SubVersion, and has been designed to work with both MATLAB and Simulink.  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/discovery/simulink-projects.html

Comment: Hi, I googled around and found github. I'm using windows. So I installed git and smartgit for gui. Works well, thank you.

Comment: @SreePrasannaRajagopal - good for you. version control is an extremely GOOD practice when it comes to software development. Saved my MSc thesis...